# Filter function calls for a contract

Tags: web3js, ethers.js

Is there a way to watch current or filter past function calls with their names in web3 or ethers, just like we can view past events using `getPastEvents` in web3?

I want to fetch only the transactions where a certain function is called within past few blocks or set a watcher for that function if possible.

Comment: Well, not in a straighforward way. That is exactly the purpose of events =)

Answer (score 1):

I think that is possible but it is the worst way and also limited. Therefore u must use events.

Anyway suppose you have a contract with an external method `myMethod(uint256,string)`:

- first you need to get the function selector (in etherjs is probably https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/abi/interface/#Interface--selectors)

  ```
  web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionSignature('myMethod(uint256,string)')
  > '0x24ee0097'
  ```
- then you need to iterate over all the Transactions, filter the transactions by (to == your contract)
- check if their inputs start with `0x24ee0097`

This will only works for external transaction (A wallet(EOA) call the function directly in your contract). It will not works for internal txs( another function or contract call your function)